# How to write a regex pattern which matches following Array?

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I want to write a regex pattern that user enters values matches the any one of the index in the following array ,can you please help me to achieve this thing...

```
$cars=['bmw','Audi','Ferari','BenZ',];
$regex_pattern=^[A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*$;  //it takes the value only string with space or without space,now i want to match the pattern with the given array values .

if(preg_match($regex_pattern,$request->search)){
    my logic
}
```

**InvalidScenarios**:

Flight

Ship

**Valid-Scenarios**:

bmw

Audi

Ferari

Benz

Comment: Why specifically regex? Looks like a simple [in_​array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) could do the job

Answer (score 0):

```
$cars=['bmw','Audi','Ferari','BenZ',];
$regex_pattern=^[A-Za-z ]+$;  //it takes the value only string with space or without space,now i want to match the pattern with the given array values .

if(preg_match($regex_pattern,$request->search)){
    my logic
}
```

Comment: if i enter `Ship` it should match the regex pattern right, so this is not my requirement

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`$matches  = preg_grep ('/^ship (\w+)/i', $cars);`
Output : []

`$matches  = preg_grep ('/^bmw (\w+)/i', $cars);`
Output : [ 0 => 'bmw' ];

It will return array of values matched.
You can check for $matches if it is an empty array that means you don't have any match.

Reference : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

Comment: Here How to pass the user entered value

Comment: ```
$search = '/^' . $request->search .'(\w+)/i';
preg_grep ($search, $cars)

```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a dynamic pattern to assert for the word in the string, and then use your regex to match only the allowed characters.

```
$cars=['bmw','Audi','Ferari','BenZ'];
$str = 'bmw
Audi
Ferari
Benz
Flight
Ship';
$regex_pattern = sprintf
("/^(?=.*\b(?:%s)\b)[A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*$/im",
    implode('|', $cars)
);
preg_match_all($regex_pattern, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "bmw"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "Audi"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Ferari"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "Benz"
}
```